# Running PySpark script with dependencies

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

On a cdh6.2.0 cluster with Spark 2.4.0 and Yarn I'm trying to submit a Python script with PySpark (and in the future I'll need to make Oozie do the submission). Cluster nodes are heterogeneous (some have CentOS and others have Debian) and the Python's installations aren't the same, but on every node there's a Pyton3.6 installation, even if with different paths on different OS. The Python script has some external dependecy, but I can't reproduce the same configuration on each node, even using Conda or configuring ad-hoc virtual environments on each node.

Looking for a solution to my problem, I found that there are two main options to menage this situation:

- istantiate on execution nodes an isolated virtual environment when submitting the script, providing a `requirements.txt` file and setting the configurations for `spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled` and `spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type`;
- distribute my dependencies using `--py-files` or `--archives` options.

I tried to use both solutions but I failed in every way.

An example of a simple script I've tried to submit (just importing fieldclimate package to test if it works):

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# test if the lib is correctly imported
from fieldclimate import FieldClimateClient

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName('spark-yarn')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)


rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1000))
print(rdd)
```

And that's an example of the `requirements.txt` file:

```
asks==2.3.6
async-generator==1.10
contextvars==2.4
h11==0.9.0
immutables==0.11
numpy==1.17.4
pandas==0.25.3
pycryptodome==3.9.4
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-fieldclimate==1.3
pytz==2019.3
six==1.13.0
sniffio==1.1.0
```

As a first approach I tried to use a virtual environment as explained [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13587). That's the command I used: `` spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled=true --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type=native --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.requirements=requirements.txt --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.path=/home/nsantolini/test_pyspark/sensors/virtual_env  --conf spark.pyspark.python=`which python3.6` script_climate.py ``

I tried different combinations for the configuration but the import didn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nsantolini/test_pyspark/sensors/script_climate.py", line 12, in <module>
    from fieldclimate import FieldClimateClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fieldclimate'
19/11/22 15:51:10 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/11/22 15:51:10 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-7caa321f-ebe3-42b4-98de-3984946a2534
```

As a second attempt I tried to zip and ship an environment with my job. An example is available [here](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/spark.html), it uses a Conda environment but online there are other similar examples that use simple virtual environment. After creating a virtual environment based on the requirements file, I just zipped id (I tried to create the archive from both outside and inside the virtual environment folder).

Trying in client-mode with the following command:

```
 PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=`which python3.6` \
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./virtual_env/bin/python3.6 \
spark-submit \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./virtual_env/bin/python3.6 \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--archives virtual_env.zip#virtual_env \
script_climate.py
```

produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nsantolini/test_pyspark/script_climate.py", line 12, in <module>
    from fieldclimate import FieldClimateClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fieldclimate'
19/11/22 16:29:16 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/11/22 16:29:16 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-a8f2c3d8-1440-4741-81b9-8480316ea0e6
```

Trying in cluster-mode with the following command:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./virtual_env/bin/python3.6 \
spark-submit \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./virtual_env/bin/python3.6 \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--archives virtual_env.zip#virtual_env \
script_climate.py
```

produced (from Yarn logs):

```
******************************************************************************

Container: container_1572511978601_0446_01_000001 on my_host_8041
LogAggregationType: AGGREGATED
======================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Fri Nov 22 16:24:41 +0100 2019
LogLength:2971
LogContents:
19/11/22 16:24:37 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
19/11/22 16:24:37 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
19/11/22 16:24:37 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
19/11/22 16:24:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn,nsantolini
19/11/22 16:24:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn,nsantolini
19/11/22 16:24:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/11/22 16:24:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/11/22 16:24:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(yarn, nsantolini); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(yarn, nsantolini); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/11/22 16:24:38 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: ApplicationAttemptId: appattempt_1572511978601_0446_000001
19/11/22 16:24:38 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Starting the user application in a separate Thread
19/11/22 16:24:38 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization...
19/11/22 16:24:38 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 1
19/11/22 16:24:38 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13, (reason: User application exited with status 1)
19/11/22 16:24:38 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:447)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:798)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:798)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkUserAppException: User application exited with 1
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner$.main(PythonRunner.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner.main(PythonRunner.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:667)
19/11/22 16:24:38 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called

End of LogType:stderr
***********************************************************************

Container: container_1572511978601_0446_01_000001 on my_host_8041
LogAggregationType: AGGREGATED
======================================================================================
LogType:stdout
LogLastModifiedTime:Fri Nov 22 16:24:41 +0100 2019
LogLength:185
LogContents:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_climate.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkConf
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

End of LogType:stdout
***********************************************************************
```

If the problem is the missing zlib package, I'm not sure I have the rights to install it on every node.

I'm pretty sure that both solutions are viable but I can't figure what I'm not doing properly. I looked for some solution integrated with Oozie too, but it didn't work anyway.

Comment: If your Hadoop Admins have set up such a heterogeneous cluster, either they have defined **YARN node labels** https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html so that you can request that your job runs _only_ on specific (e.g. CentOS) nodes; or they deserve eternal damnation http://www.pba-lille.fr/Visiter/Famille/Les-chefs-d-oeuvre-des-enfants/MOYEN-AGE-ET-RENAISSANCE/Le-Paradis-et-L-Enfer _(panel on the right)_

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think that the Yarn node labels is an enterprise solution not available on our Cloudera Community installation. The eterogenity of the cluster will be partially resolved in the next weeks when the CentOS nodes will be updated with a new Debian installation. After that all the nodes should have the same OS but I don't think that the upgrade will solve the problem with PySpark.

Comment: _"Yarn node labels is an enterprise solution"_ >> oh no it isn't. The link above points to `hadoop.apache.org` meaning it's a core, open source feature. You will find multiple presentations on that topic on `slideshare.net`